# Must a compound sentence have a comma?

Tags: commas, clauses, independent-clauses, compound-sentences

Must a compound sentence have a comma?

If it simply linking two independent clauses with a conjunction, does it require a comma? e.g.

He poured me another drink and I drank it.

If not a compound sentence, what would this be called? Simply grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Didn't you just ask that within your last question?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I did, but nobody answered precisely enough on that post, so I supposed I could've worded it better. I now see the new comment by tinfoil hat.

Comment: If you hear a comma, you should write it. Otherwise, not. If you can't hear commas you shouldn't be using them.

Comment: Re-submitting the same question is a no-no.  Please delete one of the questions.